# How to convert ng-bootstrap tabs into accordion for mobile view?

Tags: angular, tabs, accordion, ng-bootstrap

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples

How to convert these tabs showed in the above link into the accordion for mobile device with auto collapse other tab when open the other tab. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, here is the link, where the code is available.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview